# Declared module in TypeScript gets redeclared

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am experiencing something very strange at the moment.

I am simply trying to split up a Module into different files - as also described in this link https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript. So it seems to be possible.

Since that did not work I tried it in a single file (see following code) and it does not work either.

```
declare module Admin {
    export class Blubber {
    }
}

module Admin {
    export class InlineMail {

    }
}
```

The result of compilation is:

```
var Admin;
(function (Admin) {
    var InlineMail = (function () {
        function InlineMail() {
        }
        return InlineMail;
    })();
    Admin.InlineMail = InlineMail;
})(Admin || (Admin = {}));
```

The fact that "Blubber" is missing is not bad as this is meant to be defined somewhere else.
BUT: The

```
var admin
```

is ultra annoying. I declare the module and it still gets defined? That does not make sense. If I do that multiple times it compiles into multiple `var Admin`...

Can someone help with this one? How do you merge modules?

Comment: I don't think you need the declare keyword. That is for wrapping JavaScript libraries in modules I believe. If you're writing your code in typescript you shouldn't need to "declare".

Comment: Hi Gustav. Yes I know. But that is the point. There is a current "Admin"-Object available - written in JS not TS.

So Admin should be extended and not redefined. I know that you could workaround that but I think there is a Bug in TS.

Comment: What if you put the "declared" module in a d.ts file? Because that's what it is, right? A typescript definition for some javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler has to do this because, in reality, it doesn't know what order your scripts are going to load in. It's possible you have some circular dependence between `Blubber` and `InlineMail` and in reality the other half of the module is going to load later than this file.

Imagine the opposite world where TypeScript saw the the first instance of any `module` or `declare module` and said "Gotcha, it's on you to make sure that `var` exists at runtime now". You would be unable to do otherwise-sensible things like only conditionally load certain parts of your module on certain webpages. You'd also have to make sure that the loading of *otherwise order-agnostic code* would be exactly the same as the order that the compiler saw, which is insane. It would be a gigantic pain in the ass and everyone would rightfully complain about it.

The extra `var` statement is totally harmless in practice. Run your .js code through a strong minifier if needed.

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was searching for. Though - I could have thought of that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually should be okay. TypeScript is a little bit verbose in its output, but that's to be safe with whatever other JS it's working with. To start with, don't worry over the use of `var`.

```
x = 2;
var x;
console.log(x); // 2!
```

The var statement won't actually remove the existing Admin object. What's more, you're helped by this line:

```
})(Admin || (Admin = {}));
```

The method defining the InlineMail module is actually going to see and use your existing Admin object, and add to that instead of creating a new one.

If you decide to follow a similar construction for your main Admin.js, then it might not actually matter which one gets called first.

The entire `declare` block is ignored for the most part in actual code-production - all it does is tell the compiler "*This is what an Admin module looks like*" and throws an error if something doesn't match expectations. It's a bit like the difference between a Class (a blueprint) and an Object (a house)

Comment: Hi katana314. The problem is that it gets declared again. That is the problem. The problem is in the ``var Admin``. Because there is already a ``var Admin``. And adding multiple modules like this produces multiple ``var Admin`` by TS.

Comment: I thought you said that the first `var Admin` was produced by JavaScript, not TypeScript? See my first code example - there will still only be one `x` after writing `var x`. The second one will be ignored, making it safe to write twice.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The first var Admin is produced by native JS. But the problem occured with TS. Still I think you tried to tell the right thing but Ryan made it clearer. Thanks.